# How do I set an image for ContextMenuStrip items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

How do I set an image for ContextMenuStrip items? I'm using C#.

Comment: If it's WinForms: Open designer --> Righ-click on the item --> Set Image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [ToolStripItem.DisplayStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.displaystyle.aspx) Property to [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemdisplaystyle.aspx) and then set the [image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.image.aspx) property

Here's the sample from MSDN which

- gets the image from a file
- sets the style to Image and text
- aligns the image to MiddleLeft
- set the name of the itme
- sets the text align to MiddleRight
- sets the text
- and adds an Click event handler

Sample

```
this.toolStripButton1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\NewItem.bmp");
this.toolStripButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
this.toolStripButton1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
this.toolStripButton1.Name = "toolStripButton1";
this.toolStripButton1.Text = "&New";
this.toolStripButton1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
this.toolStripButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripButton1_Click);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the (drumroll...)                                       *`Image` property*!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myContextMenuStrip.ShowImageMargin = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image` Property
`DisplayStyle` must set to `ImageAndText` Or `Image`

Comment: i don't want to have only images , i want both text items and left of them images ! if my friends explain with code i will be very thankfull .